# How to extract values from inner JSONObject from a key inside of entity response output-type of an API in KOTLIN?

Tags: json, kotlin, mockito, corda, assertion

I was trying to get the array of JSONObjects from the ResponseEntity< JSONObject > variable "result".

```
 <200 OK,{"response":"success","count":0,"maintenanceDetails":[{"date":"2020\/08\/21","activity":"TestActivity","operatorName":"Operator","operator":"Mock for Party, hashCode: 552416003","status":"Open"}],"buildingId":Mock for UUID, hashCode: 2141932519},{}>
```

> Output value of result is given above.

```
val result = dashBoardService!!.getMaintenanceStateByBuildingId(id)

println("Result "+result.body["maintenanceDetails"])

val a =result.body["maintenanceDetails"] as Array<JSONObject>
println("A  "+ a.first().get("activity"))
```

I Use "as Array < JSONObject >" to convert, because result.body["maintenanceDetails"] normally comes as "Any" type, which I can't extract more. But this gives me below error.

> java.lang.ClassCastException: java.util.ArrayList cannot be cast to [Lorg.json.simple.JSONObject;

What I need is to get the first JSONObject from Array corresponds to result.body["maintenanceDetails"] so that I can use it in assert checks. Kindly help.

Comment: Use [getJsonArray("maintenanceDetails")](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/org/json/JSONObject#getjsonarray) instead.

Comment: could you pls mention the import statement of getJsonArray also?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Conversion is working to ArrayList since it is considered as util.ArrayList by Intelij, So after this I am able to get the data from inside.

```
val tempArr= result.body["maintenanceDetails"] as ArrayList<JSONObject>


assertEquals(tempArr[0]["activity"],maintenanceState.activity)
assertEquals(tempArr[0]["status"],maintenanceState.status)
```

Answer (score 1):

Use:

```
val array = JSONArray(result.body["maintenanceDetails"])
val first = array.getJSONObject(0)
```

Comment: could you pls mention the import statement of JSONArray? I tried this but I think I am having a different one!

Comment: java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: org/json/JSONArray has been compiled by a more recent version of the Java Runtime (class file version 55.0), this version of the Java Runtime only recognizes class file versions up to 52.0

This is the error I got then

Comment: You should use :` import org.json.JSONArray;`

Answer (score 1):

You can use JSONArray() to access the array inside a json object (Root) and then iterate the array to get all the json objects present in the array. Here is a sample,

```
import org.json.simple.JSONArray
import org.json.simple.JSONObject

val jsonObject = JSONObject()
val childObject = JSONObject()
childObject["date"]="10-10-2010"
childObject["operator"]="mock party"
val jsonArray = JSONArray()
jsonArray.add(0,childObject)
jsonObject["response"]="success"
jsonObject["count"]=0
jsonObject["maintenanceDetails"]=jsonArray
val json = jsonObject["maintenanceDetails"] as JSONArray
println(json[0])
val outputObject = json[0] as JSONObject
println(outputObject["operator"])
```

Output:

```
{"date":"10-10-2010","operator":"mock party"}
mock party
```

Comment: Bro can you pls show how to do this from results variable?